# Chrome Media Query w/ Scrollbars Change

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

Chrome used to improperly exclude the scroll bar in its media queries. This means that with 1000px of visible space and a 17px scroll bar, other browsers would report 1017px as a width so far as Media Query is concerned, but webkit browsers (such as Chrome and Safari) did not do this.

These browsers could hit a specific size where a scroll bar would appear in one resolution, then change resolutions to another where it would appear, then it would go back to when it didn't... the solution caused an ugly blank space to appear where the scroll bar should, but it did not. It came out looking like a glitch, and the DOM resize events did not fire properly so it was not something you could react to properly in JS.

However, now in Chrome 29, this appears to have changed. Now they are going off of how the specification works and including the scroll bar in their media query calculations... just like Firefox and Internet Explorer (and how the specification says they should have all along). This fixes the bugs, but causes another problem in that the JS to try to detect the Chrome/Safari issue now will have false positives, because it is not a concern with newer versions of Chrome and I assume eventually Opera and Safari as well.

In light of all of this, I cannot find any information anywhere on when this was fixed in either Chrome or Webkit. I hate having to resort to browser version testing in my JS to work around these flaws, but I am just guessing blindly on Chrome 29+ for the moment as a temporary patch and would love an authoritative answer... I have tested in Safari 6.0.5, but the old method is still being used...

Does anybody know in what version of Chrome and/or Webkit this was fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome is no longer using the webkit engine as of Chrome v. 28 it now uses the Blink Rendering Engine. So no need to be detecting this for chrome unless you need it for previous versions.

For more on Blink: [Blink Documnetation](http://www.chromium.org/blink)

For more on the Release: [Next Web Article on Webkit/Blink Switch](http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/04/08/its-here-google-replaces-webkit-with-blink-in-latest-build-of-chrome/)

Comment: Yep, I do need to detect for older versions unfortunately since not everybody has auto update on and all that.
In any case, at least I know when the change over happened. Thank you!